# How to correctly include templates?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am getting the following error when adding the template `Variable "addPostForm" does not exist.`

I want to include in my main template another template with a form that will be shown in a modal window

This is my controller

```
#[Route('/post/{id}/add', name: 'add_post')]
public function addPost(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) : Response 
{
    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(PostFormType::class, $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $message = $form->get('message')->getData();
        $post->setMessage($message);
        $post->setAuthor($this->getUser());

        $entityManager->persist($post);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home', ['id' => $this->getUser()->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('post/post.html.twig', [
        'addPostForm' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

And the template which is located at `templates/post/post.html.twig`

```
{{ form_start(addPostForm) }}
    {{ form_row(addPostForm.message) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Register</button>
{{ form_end(addPostForm) }}
```

You need to connect to the template, which is here `templates/home/index.html.twig`
I used the include command for this `{% include 'post/post.html.twig' %}`, but it gives an error that the variable is not found

Comment: Nice to see you are putting the submit button in the HTML and outside the form itself. It is recommended by Symfony to do it like that.

Comment: Please try to add this:  `{{ form_widget(addPostForm) }}` *before* `{{ form_row(addPostForm.message) }}` Also, which variable does not find? `addPostForm`?

Comment: As seen the variable `addPostForm` is only passed to the template `post/post.html.twig` when accessing the route `/post/{id}/add`. The variable simply doesn't exists when you render the template `templates/home/index.html.twig` and do an include of the `post` template. Either create the form in the controller where you render the `index.html.twig` template or change the modal to load the route `/post/{id}/add`

Comment: Would extending the post template from the index one be a good fit for a solution too? @DarkBee

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DarkBee

I'm create form in my index controller

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
#[Route('/home/{id}', name: 'app_home')]
public function index(User $user, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{   
    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(AddPostFormType::class, $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $message = $form->get('message')->getData();
        $post->setMessage($message);
        $post->setAuthor($this->getUser());

        $entityManager->persist($post);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home', ['id' => $this->getUser()->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
        'addPostForm' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
    ]);
}
```

}